# enum data type seems not available in bash

Tags: linux, bash, enums

Having bash, created simple scripts for accessing array element by it's index.It as follows

```
#! /bin/bash

OK_INDEX=0
CANCEL_INDEX=1
ERROR_INDEX=2
CONFIRM_INDEX=3
SAVE_INDEX=4
EXIT_INDEX=5
declare -a messageList=("ok" 
                        "cancel" 
                        "error" 
                        "confirm"
                        "save"
                        "exit")

printf "%s \n" ${messageList[$CANCEL_INDEX]}
```

from above scripts i need to declare proper index variable to retrieve valid message from array list but it likely not handy for me to declare each variable and give index to them.It is nice if variable autometically getting value as like in C for `ENUM` data type

in C it's possible by like

```
enum index { OK_INDEX, CANCEL_INDEX, ERROR_INDEX,CONFIRM_INDEX,SAVE_INDEX,EXIT_INDEX};
```

is there any alternative for `ENUM` in bash?

I found  lot but not succeded then have try some trick to achieve this it is as follows

```
ENUM=(OK_INDEX CANCEL_INDEX ERROR_INDEX CONFIRM_INDEX SAVE_INDEX EXIT_INDEX)

maxArg=${#ENUM[@]}

for ((i=0; i < $maxArg; i++)); do
    name=${ENUM[i]}
    declare -r ${name}=$i
done
```

So form above code snippet i successfully created constant but it seems lengthy means just declaring variable i need to write 5-10 lines code which is not fair.

So any one have another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following fragment of code ... I guess that it is what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u 
DEBUG=1

# This funcion allow to declare enum "types", I guess
enum ()
{
    # skip index ???
    shift
    AA=${@##*\{} # get string strip after { 
    AA=${AA%\}*} # get string strip before }
    AA=${AA//,/} # delete commaa  
    ((DEBUG)) && echo $AA
    local I=0
    for A in $AA ; do
        eval "$A=$I"
        ((I++))
    done
}

### Main program 
# Just declare enum as you need
enum index { OK_INDEX, CANCEL_INDEX, ERROR_INDEX, CONFIRM_INDEX, SAVE_INDEX, EXIT_INDEX };
# Print value of enumerated items
echo $OK_INDEX
echo $CANCEL_INDEX 
echo $ERROR_INDEX  
echo $CONFIRM_INDEX
echo $SAVE_INDEX
echo $EXIT_INDEX

# Use enumerated index in program
I=CONFIRM_INDEX
case $I in  
    OK_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;
    CANCEL_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;
    ERROR_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;
    CONFIRM_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;  
    SAVE_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;  
    EXIT_INDEX )
        echo "Process here when index is $I"
    ;;  
esac  

exit 0
```

Comment: really appreciate you help but it also one trick to declared variable write some code.In your script you implement `enum` functionality which give index to each element.Anyway got new idea.

Comment: What was the point of `index` anyway (prior to ignoring it)? a type identifier..?..because that _really_ doesn't make sense. Is still a cute function, nonetheless.

But I would suggest either:
  a. Get rid of `index` altogether, or 
  b. Prepend/Append (user preference) uppercase'd value of `index` variable onto each of the enumerated identifiers

Answer (score 2):

My take on this:

```
function \
   _enum()
{
   ## void
   ## (
   ##    _IN $@ : [ array<string> ] list
   ## )

   local list=("$@")
   local len=${#list[@]}

   for (( i=0; i < $len; i++ )); do
      eval "${list[i]}=$i"
   done
}
```

Example:

```
ENUM=(
   OK_INDEX
   CANCEL_INDEX
   ERROR_INDEX
   CONFIRM_INDEX
   SAVE_INDEX
   EXIT_INDEX
) && _enum "${ENUM[@]}"

echo "OK_INDEX = "$OK_INDEX
echo "CANCEL_INDEX = "$CANCEL_INDEX
echo "ERROR_INDEX = "$ERROR_INDEX
echo "CONFIRM_INDEX = "$CONFIRM_INDEX
echo "SAVE_INDEX = "$SAVE_INDEX
echo "EXIT_INDEX = "$EXIT_INDEX
```

Output

```
OK_INDEX = 0
CANCEL_INDEX = 1
ERROR_INDEX = 2
CONFIRM_INDEX = 3
SAVE_INDEX = 4
EXIT_INDEX = 5
```

I find this to be the cleanest and most straightforward approach.

Another solution is to assign values to an associative array to make an enum set with the variable name as the prefix. This allows introspection of the enum by walking through all available values and their associated key names:

```
function \
   _enum_set()
{
   ## void
   ## (
   ##    _IN  $1 : [ string ] prefix
   ##    _IN ... : [ array<string> ] list
   ## )

   local prefix=$1
   local list=("$@")
   local len=${#list[@]}

   declare -g -A $prefix

   for (( i=0; i < $len; i++ )); do
      # Skip the first argument
      [[ $i = 0 ]] &&
         continue

      eval "$prefix[${list[$i]}]=$(( $i - 1 ))"
   done
}
```

Example (looping):

```
ENUM=(
   OK
   CANCEL
   ERROR
   CONFIRM
   SAVE
   EXIT
) && _enum_set ENUM_INDEX "${ENUM[@]}"

echo ""
for i in "${!ENUM_INDEX[@]}"; do
   echo "ENUM_INDEX[$i] = "${ENUM_INDEX[$i]}
done
```

Output:

```
ENUM_INDEX[CONFIRM] = 3
ENUM_INDEX[OK] = 0
ENUM_INDEX[EXIT] = 5
ENUM_INDEX[ERROR] = 2
ENUM_INDEX[SAVE] = 4
ENUM_INDEX[CANCEL] = 1
```

Example (explicit):

```
ENUM=(
   OK
   CANCEL
   ERROR
   CONFIRM
   SAVE
   EXIT
) && _enum_set ENUM_INDEX "${ENUM[@]}"

echo "ENUM_INDEX[OK] = "${ENUM_INDEX[OK]}
echo "ENUM_INDEX[CANCEL] = "${ENUM_INDEX[CANCEL]}
echo "ENUM_INDEX[ERROR] = "${ENUM_INDEX[ERROR]}
echo "ENUM_INDEX[CONFIRM] = "${ENUM_INDEX[CONFIRM]}
echo "ENUM_INDEX[SAVE] = "${ENUM_INDEX[SAVE]}
echo "ENUM_INDEX[EXIT] = "${ENUM_INDEX[EXIT]}
```

Output:

```
ENUM_INDEX[OK] = 0
ENUM_INDEX[CANCEL] = 1
ENUM_INDEX[ERROR] = 2
ENUM_INDEX[CONFIRM] = 3
ENUM_INDEX[SAVE] = 4
ENUM_INDEX[EXIT] = 5
```

Note that associative arrays have no defined order but can always be sorted at a later point.

Answer (score 2):

You can consolidate some of the lines:

```sh
$ for i in \
  E_OK E_CANCEL E_ERROR E_CONFIRM E_SAVE E_EXIT; do \
  readonly ${i}=$((x++)); done

$ for i in ${!E_@}; do echo $i=${!i}; done
```

Another version using mapfile callback function:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t -c 1 -C 'f(){ readonly $2=$1; }; f' << \
EOF
E_OK
E_CANCEL
E_ERROR
E_CONFIRM
E_SAVE
E_EXIT
EOF

for i in ${!E_@}; do echo $i=${!i}; done
```

Output:

```sh
E_CANCEL=1
E_CONFIRM=3
E_ERROR=2
E_EXIT=5
E_OK=0
E_SAVE=4
```

Comment: Upvote for not using `eval`. I tweaked this to make an `enum` function like other answers suggest, also using a heredoc to make the list more readable and `readonly` instead of `declare` to make the vars global (could also use `declare -rg`):

```
enum () {
  local varName
  local x=0
  while read -r varName
  do
    readonly ${varName}=$((x++))
  done
}

enum <<'EOL'
E_OK
E_CANCEL
E_ERROR
E_SAVE
E_EXIT
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical workaround when an enum is wanted is to use normal strings.  In these cases I even omit the otherwise mandatory quotes around variable evaluation:

```
 state=IDLE
 ...
 while [ $state = IDLE ]
 do
   ...
   if condition
   then
     state=BUSY
   fi
   ...
   if condition2
   then
     state=ERROR
   fi
   ...
 done
 if [ $state = ERROR ]
 then
   ...
 fi
```

This way, of course, you have just the basic functionality of named states and neither of the following typically associated features of enums:

1. declaration of all possible values (self-documenting code)
2. associated number for each value (matter of taste if this is a feature or a wart)
3. no prevention/detection of mistypings (but this is rare in scripts anyway)

Comment: As you already know that Typically enum improved program readability,enumerated constants are generated automatically.So it will helpful me if i declared array more then 100 items then i just need to add index name not require to assign value.without enum if i missed to assign value then something will go weird.that's why i prefer enum in my scripts.Thanks for your reply.